# Is there a better way to handle CRUD operations in Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, orm, crud

I've been stuck on this forever now because my questions often get ignored and the online docs are not clear. Apparently to simplify CRUD operations in Android you can use an ORM, but things like ORMlite seem very limited (especially if you have objects that have lists of objects) and seems to work better for very very simple cases.

What is my alternative? Otherwise I have to write at least four methods per object for creating, retrieving, updating, and deleting, and that class blows up in size real fast.

So what do people do? I feel alone out here.

Comment: "So what do people do?" -- some use one of [the dozens of ORM libraries](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/69). Some use alternative database engines, like Realm or Couchbase Mobile. Some write straight to a hosted backend using a Web service API. Some write JSON or XML to local files, using libraries like Gson. Some use `ObjectOutputStream`. And I am sure that there are other approaches that I am forgetting.

Comment: None of these do what I need -- am I going crazy? Am I completely misunderstanding what an ORM is supposed to be for here? Why does every ORM seem to only handle individual, single objects to a single row in a table? No cascading persistence / deletion / etc?

Comment: "Why does every ORM seem to only handle individual, single objects to a single row in a table?" -- some certainly handle relations (e.g., greenDAO, DBFlow, RushORM, ActiveAndroid, to name four).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer depends on what you want to do, i.e. do you need to maintain CRUD operations for all the entities in your domain.

If you need to, then you will have to sort of deal with it. And if you have to deal with it, then, in my personal experience, you are better off using traditional ORM frameworks than adhoc ones. Like JPA (e.g.Hibernate) vs other smaller ones. Because the heavyweights will really help you as your domain grows. Everyone will mock you when you say you are using this, but believe me - when your domain grows, you will feel the difference. True, you can be a very principled programmer and do well without using this, but that's not true for everyone.

And if you don't need to deal with all of them, you can then focus on the ones that will quickly get you started. My personal favorite has been [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/getting-started.html). [Spring JDBC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) is also a fantastic one and can get you up and running super fast.

Comment: The problem is that every ORM framework I come across simply does not do what I want. Like for example if I have a Book object that has a List of Page objects, such that if I persist the Book, it also persists all the Pages. That's it! It seems so simple but nothing out there does it.

Comment: @ArukaJ Have you looked at cascading operations in JPA? They store relationships without you storing them explicitly. You just add pages to the book object and store book which will automatically store pages as well.

Comment: I couldn't find any obvious/clear examples; the Java tutorials are so incredibly hard to read.

Comment: @ArukaJ take a look at the one-to-many example in this article: https://vladmihalcea.com/2015/03/05/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/

Comment: The part starting with "The most common Parent – Child association consists of a one-to-many and a many-to-one relationship, where the cascade being useful for the one-to-many side only:" ?

Comment: @ArukaJ correct. See how the Post and the associated Comments are persisted. Simply create the object with the associations and save the root which saves all the children too.

Comment: The caveat being the the name in the string has to match the name of the field in the child class?

Comment: @ArukaJ where's name in the child class here? Comment doesn't have a name. Post and Comment are associated by postId which is the foreign key. Database 101.

Comment: where it says `mappedBy = "post"`

Comment: Also I made a thread here in case this is easier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946008/how-do-i-define-what-an-annotation-does-making-my-own-orm

Comment: @ArukaJ correct. You should accept this as answer if it helped you.

Answer (score -1):

Try some [sugar](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html), I find its use really productive.

It always boils down to what you want to achieve.

1. More control/complex solutions = more work
2. Using the basics = smart choice

My suggestion, just keep it simple an orm will in most cases save you time and effort.