# How to pass / access annotation information?

Tags: java, android, orm, annotations

Example of my current Book class which I am trying to apply annotations to:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "books")
public class Book {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int mId;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "book_name", canBeNull = false)
    private String mBookName;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false)
    private String mAuthorName;

....
```

My annotation interfaces:

pu

```
blic @interface DatabaseTable {
    String tableName() default "";
}
```

and

```
public @interface DatabaseField {
    String columnName() default "";
    boolean generatedId() default false;
    boolean canBeNull() default true;
}
```

And then in my MainActivity I tried:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String LOG_TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Book book = new Book("The Book of Kittens", "Mr. Smith");

        outputInfoAboutClass((Class<? extends DatabaseTable>) book.getClass());
    }

    private void outputInfoAboutClass(Class<? extends DatabaseTable> aClass) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Class simple name: " + aClass.getSimpleName());

        for (Field field : aClass.getFields()) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Field name: " + field.getName());
        }

        for (Annotation annotation : aClass.getAnnotations()) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Annotation name: " + annotation.toString());
        }

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "End of logging!");
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is make a general method that accepts a class and have it be able to uncover the underlying annotations and their values/attributes, but I think I am going about it all wrong. For example how would I take in this class (might be a Book, might be something else), and be able to determine "This is the tableName, these are the member variables we've defined as DatabaseFields, these are the settings we set for those fields," etc.

Comment: Side note: [Martin Fowler's article on ORM hate](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/OrmHate.html) is a good read for anyone considering "rolling their own" ORM.

Comment: Before I even click that link, is it going to offer the predictable advice of "Basically don't do it, just use a pre-existing one"?

Comment: It doesn't, actually. It always "depends". But writing even a simple ORM is quite a lot of work.

Comment: i don't know what to do. I feel like my alternative is to just write a crapton of CRUD methods that all pretty much look the same but differ in the objects/fields/table names/column names.

Comment: You don't "define" what an annotation does. You write code to look for the annotation, then write more code to do *something* based on what you find.

Comment: @Andreas So in the example I posted, what does it mean then to have annotations for DatabaseTable and DatabaseField? Does this not imply that  there are two interfaces named DatabaseTable and Databasefield, and then some other class that implements those interfaces?

Comment: @ArukaJ No. Though Java annotations use `@interface`, it is not an interface that you *implement*. Instead, for example, you write some code to create a `SELECT` statement for retrieving records from the database to return a `List<Book>`. To do this you need to know the table name, so your code looks for the `@DatabaseTable` annotation to see if it has a `tableName` value. If it does, you use that as the table name. If it doesn't, you default to use the class name as the table name. Examining the fields you'll be able to build `SELECT mId, book_name FROM books`. And so on.

Comment: Is my new code on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has some good documentation on this:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/hunter-meta-2-098036.html

The topic is complex and there are a lot of steps to it, so it is not suitable for a quick summary here. You declare a special kind of interface using `@interface TypeName` and fill in some logic, typically using reflection.

It is something you should study thoroughly and practice before releasing code to clients.